# Concatenate data into one variable

Tags: xslt, transformation

Source file looks like below.

```
</StsRsn>
<AddtlStsRsnInf>/00000002/Level 2 Reject</AddtlStsRsnInf>
<AddtlStsRsnInf>The Transaction Reference Number is</AddtlStsRsnInf>
<AddtlStsRsnInf> not unique.</AddtlStsRsnInf>
</StsRsnInf>
```

now the requirement is to concatenate the `<AddtlStsRsnInf>` value into one signle variable.

Could you please let me know how can i do it.

Thanks and Regards,
Kiran.

Comment: This is duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207841/concatenate-data-into-one-variable . So, I vote for CLOSE. @kiram: if you are not going to accept any answer from your other post, you should edit that with better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<xl:variable name="var" select="concat(AddtlStsRsnInf[1],AddtlStsRsnInf[2],AddtlStsRsnInf[3])"/>
```

if the number of children is variable:

```
<xl:variable name="var"><xsl:apply-templates select="AddtlStsRsnInf"/><xsl:variable/>
```

Comment: I get the feeling the amount of nodes might vary.

Comment: Hello Pierre, 

Thanks for you quick response. but in my case amount of nodes will vary. is there any way of doing it dynamically?. 

Thanks and Regards,
Kiran.